# TFS daily build - Log and categorize compiler warnings

Tags: visual-studio, build-process, compiler-warnings

Is there a possibility to log the compiler warnings of the daily build (TFS) in a file and categorize them? We are using Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Check your drop directory.  As part of the build, it should create a file called `ErrorsWarningsLog.txt`.  This file contains a list of all of the errors and warnings that were generated as part of the build.

You would have to write a custom routine to parse these, but it should be relatively easy to do so, as it is a plain text file.

Comment: yes this helps. Any idea why in that file does't contain as many warnings as compared to my errorlist when building the project on my local machine?

Comment: Take a look at the parameters passed to the compiler as part of th build. I wouldn't be surprised if it is suppressing some of the errors on he command line.